# Force navigation to app root on refresh backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, authentication

I'm wondering if there is a way to force my App to navigate to a certain route when the router is initialized. Currently when i refresh my app at lets say 'myapp/page/user'
The app re-initializes at that fragment.

Is there anyway to force it to refresh to 'myapp/' ?

I have tried using Backbone.history.navigate - from within the router.initialize() - which doesn't work (and probably shouldn't) .

I have also tried window.location.href = ''; before App.start() - which seems to work on other fragments but not the root.

The main issue is I want to check for token in session storage and if it is not there to return the user to the login page...

Thanks in adavnce..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should solve your problem;

```
Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true,
    root: "myapp/"
});
```

Check this **[backbone reference](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start)**.

**Note** hash-based history in Internet Explorer relies on an , be sure to call start() only after the DOM is ready. (Via [backbonejs.org](http://backbonejs.org))

```
$(function(){
  new WorkspaceRouter();
  new HelpPaneRouter();
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had managed to force it with window.href() but it wasn't a very nice fix - this is much better. Cheers